# Is it inefficient to import all my web components with individual <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm making a site using Express + EJS. I need the site to be server side rendered so I'm using web components without shadow dom. I use a separate EJS view per page type (e.g. home, post, page).

If I'm loading the post.ejs view when I visit example.com/post/my-post, I need to import the web component classes to register my web components on the page, for example if my HTML has:

```
<navbar-element>, <big-button>, and <clock-element>
```

how bad is it to put

```
<script src="/javascript/components/navbar-element.js" defer></script>
<script src="/javascript/components/big-button.js" defer></script>
<script src="/javascript/components/clock-element.js" defer></script>
```

in my head? I'm concerned because in the event that I have, say, 50 components on a single page, that's 50 additional HTTP requests to download all those scripts. Right now the performance is better than using javascript modules, but I'm not sure if a page with a lot of components making many HTTP requests to download all those scripts is bad. If there are faster yet still simple alternatives, I'd love to hear them. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It all depends on the number of components and their size. Even 50 components is not a big problem for a modern browser, which is very efficient in loading static assets in parallels. The difference almost always will be negligible if you do not have a heavy Single Page application.

However, if you MEASURED your performance in 50 separate files vs putting it all in one file, and decided that it is indeed a problem, you can use tools like Webpack to package all of your JS files into one automatically, while keeping the source files as separate files.

However, it is yet another dependency for your project, and introducing another step in your development process, so called BUILD, and you need to think hard on whether it is worth it in your case.